# Ember build failure. ember-network/assets/module-template.js.t missing

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

As one can see in the title, I have a `ember build` failure and I have yet again no idea what the problem is this time. I don't even know what `ember-network` is even part of or why it needs a module-template.js.t file.

```
[folatt@ArkOS-Dev genesis]$ ember build
WARNING: Node v7.7.3 is not tested against Ember CLI on your platform. We recommend that you use the most-recent "Active LTS" version of Node.js.                                                                                                                                               
cleaning up...
Build failed.
The Broccoli Plugin: [object Object] failed with:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/ember-network/assets/module-template.js.t'
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:967:11)
    at Template.currentTemplateFile (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/broccoli-templater/index.js:22:18)
    at Template.processAndCacheFile (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/broccoli-templater/index.js:45:27)
    at /home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/broccoli-templater/node_modules/broccoli-filter/index.js:43:23
    at /home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/promise-map-series/index.js:11:14
    at tryCatch (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:539:12)
    at invokeCallback (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:554:13)
    at /home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:629:16
    at flush (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2414:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at: 
undefined
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "genesis",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Small description for genesis goes here",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "2.5.x",
    "ember-cli": "2.12.x",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "2.0.x",
    "ember-cli-babel": "5.2.x",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "1.3.x",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "1.1.x",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "0.3.x",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.6.x",
    "ember-cli-jshint": "2.0.x",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "3.1.x",
    "ember-cli-release": "0.2.x",
    "ember-cli-shims": "1.0.x",
    "ember-cli-sri": "2.1.x",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "1.1.x",
    "ember-cli-tutorial-style": "0.0.x",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "1.2.x",
    "ember-data": "2.12.x",
    "ember-export-application-global": "1.1.x",
    "ember-load-initializers": "0.6.x",
    "ember-resolver": "2.1.x",
    "ember-simple-auth": "1.2.x",
    "ember-simple-auth-token": "2.1.x",
    "ember-source": "2.11.x",
    "ember-welcome-page": "2.0.x",
    "loader.js": "4.2.x",
    "typeface-fira-sans": "0.0.x"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.12.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "font-awesome": "4.7.x",
    "lato-font": "3.0.x",
    "semantic-ui-ember": "^2.0.1",
    "socket.io-client": "1.7.x"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ember install ember-network`

For whatever reason `yarn` doesn't install `ember-network` fully.